# Passing a HashMap which contains non Serializable object to another Fragment

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, android-bundle

Here is my non Serializable class:

```
class Foo(val foo: String)
```

When I try to put it as an arguments it won't compile:

```
MainFragment().apply {
    arguments = Bundle().apply {
        val foo = Foo("foo!")
        putSerializable("key", foo) // compile error
    }
}
```

But If I put it into a HashMap then I can put the HashMap as an argument:

```
MainFragment().apply {
    arguments = Bundle().apply {
        val foo = Foo("foo!")
        val hashMap = hashMapOf("foo" to foo)
        putSerializable("key", hashMap) // compile
    }
}
```

And when I try to get `Foo` instance from the HashMap during Fragment creation, I'm expecting an error like `NotSerializableException` because `Foo` class is not serializable, but it works fine:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val hashMap = arguments?.getSerializable("key") as HashMap<String, Foo> // unchecked cast warning
    Log.d(TAG, "${hashMap["foo"]?.foo}") // It works fine without an exception
}
```

And it survives during the configuration changes as well. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer

It turns out my app got the RuntimeException when the app goes to the background.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.serializationsample.ui.main.Foo@378ca1e
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1799)
    ...
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:5112)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

I guess the actual serialization is happened by the `ActivityManager` when an app goes to the background but not the fragment creation or the configuration changes. Because the `ActivityManager` handles the serialized `Bundle` via IPC technique to take care of the process death and re-creation of an app.